# A heap has been corrupted opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, assertions

I get corrupt heap error message after escaping scope. Debug assertion fails in debug_heap.cpp at _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block)

```
#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2\nonfree\features2d.hpp"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Mat img = imread(argv[1]);

    SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);

    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

    detector.detect(img, keypoints);

    return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT
Fixed. The problem was with linking. I used visual studio 2015 and opencv 2.49 x86 vc10. vc10 is for visual studio 2010. Ran the some program in visual studio 2010 and works just fine.

Comment: Why not submit new issue right here https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues ? BTW, you should check img.data for not null, because imread can fail.

Comment: Implement error checking, and use a debugger

Comment: @SergeiNikulov Why would this freshman bother the team of highly professional OpenCV programmers? There is 99.99% chance that error is in his code.

Comment: I fail to see reasons for having the OP down voted. Although no my area of expertise, he provides 1./ the error; 2./ where it happens; 3./ sample code. No matter how basic the question, or how wrong the OP's attempt, not sure he deserves the kind of critique for asking this question the way he did.

Comment: There possibly some important info missing: What is the argument you give to the program?

Comment: Argument is the path to an image. I have checked that the image is loading correctly

Comment: please check that you didn't link debug libraries in release mode (or vice-versa) and/or 64 bit in 32 mode (or vice-versa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get corrupt heap error message after escaping scope.

if you are sure that the error raises at the `}` exactly, then this is not problem in your code. It just you are not linking OpenCV correctly. Mismatch between x64 and x86 or mismatch between the C++ runtime-library. So just make sure everything is linked well.

Comment: Not at all. It just means that he has undefined behavior in his program and everything can happen.

Comment: I am sure that it happens at } because I surrounded the inner code in a different scope {} and it failed at }

Comment: @Drop: I know that my assumption is not based on a real clue. But 99% of times that some one faces this error with OpenCV, it is from bad linking

Comment: @DainiusKavoliūnas try to just run this code : Mat img = imread(argv[1]); without the detecor .. would it reproduce ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi no, it doesn't

Comment: I tried your code on my machine and I could not reproduce at all. So, you have just to make sure it was linked correctly